# The project integrated myfatoorah-reactnative package reported an error when running: No signature of method

Tags: react-native

myfatoorah-reactnative version:1.0.3
react-native version:0.61.5

The following is the error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\myproject\node_modules\myfatoorah-reactnative\android\build.gradle' line: 58
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':myfatoorah-reactnative'.

> No signature of method: build_972h5xp1zhm2xdbmxymdl0hqg.android() is applicabl
> e for argument types: (build_972h5xp1zhm2xdbmxymdl0hqg$_run_closure2) values: [b
> uild_972h5xp1zhm2xdbmxymdl0hqg$_run_closure2@791bf799]

The content of line 58 of build.gradle is:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("compileSdkVersion")

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("minSdkVersion")
    targetSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("targetSdkVersion")
    buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }

  lintOptions {
    disable "GradleCompatible"
  }
  buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

How to fixed?Thank you.

I executed gradlew clean but it didn't work